# Is Google Drive API enabled for an account only provides full permission to that drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have a Google drive location that is shared for me and I have the editor permission in that folder. This means, I'm not the owner of that location but I can write to that location.

My use case is, I need to write a file (which is a report) to this location from my application. My email id is **my_name@company_name.com**. I have enabled Google drive API on this account and got the credentials.json file. Then I figured out, with this credential file, I can access my entire drive.

What worries me is, if I use my credentials for an application that is not owned by me, that may be a threat in the future? Is there a way to trim down the permission of this credentials.json file to that particular folder?

Or using client's google account for this is the only right option? In that case, if we use single google account for multiple projects, does every credentials.json we create has the same level of permission?

Answer (score 1):

- APIs are enabled per GCP project.
- [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) to those APIs are requested by your account (client) with the credentials objects that you build, which include the `.json` file and the scopes your app is requesting.
- The consent screen then appears to the user (you also) to authorize the application to make use of those scopes to make requests to the API.

You should always read carefully the scopes requested by third-party applications to which you give consent. As you may be giving consent to access your whole drive for example, or send emails on your behalf. But FYI apps that request **restricted scopes** go through heavy and expensive verification for security and compliance with Google.